# Admob implementation Error in windows phone

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, admob

I have tried  to use Admob in windows application . I have followed  http://admobwp7.codeplex.com/ video  to implement Admob in my app

My XAML code as follows :

```
<adMob7:adMobRenderer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,308,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                              Width="480" Height="55"
                              PublisherID="mypublisherID" TestMode="True"/>
```

When i tried to build the application i got error like  this

> The tag 'adMobRenderer' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:adMob7'. 
>   How to solve this problem ?

Comment: Have you add `adMob.dll` to your toolkit ?

Comment: yes i have used  adMob7.dll as it was told in video

Comment: add this `xmlns:adMob7="clr-namespace:adMob7;assembly=adMob7"` in your XAML under `<phone:PhoneApplicationPage />`

Comment: Still same error : Error The tag 'adMobRenderer' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:adMob7;assembly=adMob7'.

Comment: just try this in sample new application may works

Comment: Ok Its working but adds are not displaying.

Comment: Yeah it showing only white space for me also :(

Comment: please accept my ans if u feel my ans is solves your current problem

Comment: please Let me know if u get adds using this or any other possible solution for this problem.

Comment: did you getting any adds using adMob???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every thing looks fine try to create new sample application may works(i think you added this dll without unblocking it, after unblocking also it showing errors i think this is bug in visual studio this happens for me also )